# How to group multiple calls to function that creates headless Chrome instance in GraphQL

Tags: node.js, graphql, puppeteer

I have a NodeJS server running GraphQL. One of my queries gets a list of "projects" from an API and returns a URL. This URL is then passed to another function which gets a screenshot of that website (using a NodeJS package which is a wrapper around Puppeteer).

```
{
  projects {
    screenshot {
      url
    }
  }
}
```

My issue is, that when I run this, if there is more than say a couple of projects that it needs to go and generate a screenshot for it. It runs the screenshot function for each data response object (See below) and therefore creates a separate headless browser on the server, so my server rapidly runs out of memory and crashes.

```
{
  "data": {
    "projects": [
      {
        "screenshot": {
          "url": "https://someurl.com/randomid/screenshot.png"
        }
      },
      {
        "screenshot": {
          "url": "https://someurl.com/randomid/screenshot.png"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is a simplified version of the code I have for the screenshot logic for context:

```
const webshotScreenshot = (title, url) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

    /** Create screenshot options */
    const options = {
      height: 600,
      scaleFactor: 2,
      width: 1200,
      launchOptions: {
        headless: true,
        args: ['--no-sandbox']
      }
    };

    /** Capture website */
    await captureWebsite.base64(url.href, options)
      .then(async response => {
        /** Create filename and location */
        let folder = `output/screenshots/${_.kebabCase(title)}`;

        /** Create directory */
        createDirectory(folder);

        /** Create filename */
        const filename = 'screenshot.png';
        const fileOutput = `${folder}/${filename}`;

        return await fs.writeFile(fileOutput, response, 'base64', (err) => {
          if (err) {
            // handle error
          }

          /** File saved successfully */
          resolve({
            fileOutput
          });
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        // handle error
      });
  });
};
```

What I'd like to know, is how I could modify this logic, to:

1. Avoid creating a headless instance for every call to the function? Essentially group/batch every URL provided in the response and process it in one go
2. And anything I can do to help reduce the load on the server when this processing is happening so that I don't run out of memory?

I have done a lot now with Node args and setting memory limits etc. But the main thing now I think is making this as efficient as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize [dataloader](https://github.com/graphql/dataloader) to batch your calls to whatever function gets the screenshots. This function should take an array of URLs and return a Promise that resolves with the array of resulting images.

```
const DataLoader = require('dataloader')

const screenshotLoader = new DataLoader(async (urls) => {
  // see below
})

// Inject a new DataLoader instance into your context, then inside your resolver
screenshotLoader.load(yourUrl)
```

It doesn't look like `capture-website` supports passing in multiple URLs. That means, each call to `captureWebsite.base64` will spin up a new puppeteer instance. So, `Promise.all` is out, but you have a couple of options:

1. Handle the screen captures sequentially. This will be slow, but should ensure only one instance of puppeteer is up at a time.

```
const images = []
for (const url in urls) {
  const image = await captureWebsite.base64(url, options)
  images.push(image)
}
return images
```

2. Utilize `bluebird` or a similar library to run the requests concurrently but with a limit:

```
const concurrency = 3 // 3 at a time
return Bluebird.map(urls, (url) => {
  return captureWebsite.base64(url, options)
}, { concurrency })
```

3. Switch to using puppeteer directly, or some different library that supports taking multiple screenshots.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']});
const page = await browser.newPage();

for (const url in urls) {
  const image = await captureWebsite.base64(url, options)
  await page.goto(url);
  await page.screenshot(/* path and other screenshot options */);
}

await browser.close();
```